# How to delete wav files older than 5 minutes in Python

Tags: python, file, flask, operating-system

I need to delete wav files from a folder. I can list files but i dont know how to delete them. If folder older than 5 minutes and its a wav file it need to be deleted. And i need to do it in flask.

**My flask code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import inference
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/sentez", methods = ["POST"])
def sentez():
    if request.method == "POST":
        list_of_files = os.listdir('static')
        print(list_of_files)
        metin = request.form["metin"]
        created_audio, file_path = inference.create_model(metin)
        return render_template("index.html", my_audio = created_audio, audio_path = file_path)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.remove()` function

```
import time
# time.time() gives you the current time
# os.path.getmtime(path) give you the modified time for a file
for filename in list_of_files:
    if filename[-3:]!='wav':
        continue

    modified_time=os.path.getmtime(filename)
    if time.time()-modified_time > 300: #time in seconds
        os.remove(filename)
```

So your code will finally look like this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import inference
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/sentez", methods = ["POST"])
def sentez():
    if request.method == "POST":
        list_of_files = os.listdir('static')
        print(list_of_files)
        for filename in list_of_files:
            if filename[-3:]!='wav':
                continue
            modified_time=os.path.getmtime(filename)
            if time.time()-modified_time > 300: #time in seconds
                os.remove(filename)
        metin = request.form["metin"]
        created_audio, file_path = inference.create_model(metin)
        return render_template("index.html", my_audio = created_audio, audio_path = file_path)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run();
```

Comment: I wasnt able to try this. I will try today and write the result. Thank you.

Comment: It gives "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '27161.wav'" error. I think it happens because wav files is not in the root fodler they are in the ~/static folder. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I solved the problem but this time it doesnt check for a modified time. It deletes all wav files.

Comment: I change 5 with 300 and its working now. I think that number is for second?

Comment: oops. basically its 5 seconds. you will need to put it 300 as 5minutes is equal to 300 seconds